# Compare rising value and return max

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, node-red

I have a payload that counts up to a number, when something in the field hits it resets back to zero and starts the count again.
I'm trying to capture and return the max number before the reset.
Due to outside restrictions I don't always see the 0 so I can't use that.

```
ManTime = msg.payload;
var ManArr = [];
var manMax;

if (ManTime <  manMax) {
    ManArr.unshift(ManMax)
    manMax = 0;
} else {
    manMax = ManTime
}

msg = {
    ManMax: manMax,
    ManTime: ManTime,
    ManArr: ManArr

}
```

What I expect this to do is compare the current reading against the last reading, if it is lower add the old reading to the array.

This is a nodered flow so the code is ran everytime the payload changes, which is just a number

Example input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1

Expected output: 5, 4, 3

Comment: What is `msg.payload`? Is it an array or just a number? Are you running this code every time you get a message? If so, `manMax` will be reset to 0 every time you run it, so setting it to `ManTime` is useless. Please show how you are calling this code.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Its in a nodered flow so it runs everytime the payload changes, which is just a number.

Comment: Please provide sample input and corresponding expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For this task, I would first extract all those `payload` property values, so to get a simple array of numbers.

Then use `filter` to find those entries that are greater than the entry that follows it (if any):

```js
let messages = [
    {payload: 1}, {payload: 2}, {payload: 3}, {payload: 4}, { payload: 5 },
    {payload: 1}, {payload: 2}, {payload: 3}, {payload: 4},
    {payload: 1}, {payload: 2}, {payload: 3},
    {payload: 0}, {payload: 1}
];

let numbers = messages.map(({payload}) => payload);
let result = numbers.filter((payload, i) => payload > numbers[i+1]);

console.log(result);
```

If you get the input one by one, then:

```js
class Processor {
    constructor() {
        this.lastPayload = NaN;
        this.peeks = [];
    }
    process(msg) {
        if (msg.payload < this.lastPayload) {
            this.peeks.push(this.lastPayload);
        }
        this.lastPayload = msg.payload;
    }
} 

// simulate arrival of messages:
let messages = [
    {payload: 1}, {payload: 2}, {payload: 3}, {payload: 4}, { payload: 5 },
    {payload: 1}, {payload: 2}, {payload: 3}, {payload: 4},
    {payload: 1}, {payload: 2}, {payload: 3},
    {payload: 0}, {payload: 1}
];

let processor = new Processor;
for (let msg of messages) processor.process(msg); 
console.log(processor.peeks);
```

Comment: I don't get my input like that, payload is an amount of seconds, it constantly rises until the conditions are met. So for each run of the code I just get 1 number.

Comment: See addition to answer.